# Fetch and bulk collect from a REF CURSOR returned by a procedure

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g, cursor, oracle11gr2

I have a stored procedure that has a `SYS_REFCURSOR` as an `OUT` parameter. The signature is, for example, as follows:

```
PROCEDURE myProc(p_someID IN INTEGER, p_cursor OUT SYS_REFCURSOR);
```

I call this procedure from a function, where I have to copy a column named `clientID` from the `p_cursor` to a scalar nested table.

I am doing as follows:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION myFunction
    RETURN sys_refcursor
IS
    someID      INTEGER       := 1234;
    myCursor    SYS_REFCURSOR;
    TYPE t_clientID_nt IS TABLE OF NUMBER(16,0);
    clientID_nt t_clientID_nt;
    otherID     SYS_REFCURSOR;
BEGIN
    myProc (someID, myCursor);
    FOR i IN myCursor
    LOOP
        clientID_nt.EXTEND;
        clientID_nt (clientID_nt.COUNT) := i.clientID;
    END LOOP;


    -- Other code that opens the cursor otherID
    -- based on the IDs in clientID_nt
    ...
    ... 
    RETURN otherID;
END;
/
```

When I try to compile this function, the error I get is:

```
PLS-00221: 'CLIENTID_NT' is not a procedure or is undefined
```

and it is at line 11 of the code.

Any help on how to fetch and bulk collect from such a cursor is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not allowed to use cursor variables in the `for` cursor loop (`FOR i IN myCursor`). You have to fetch from the cursor variable explicitly one row at a time, using `FETCH INTO` statement and regular loop statement for instance or use `FETCH BULK COLLECT INTO` to populate a collection. For instance:

```
SQL> declare
  2    TYPE t_clientID_nt IS TABLE OF dual%rowtype;
  3    clientID_nt t_clientID_nt;
  4  
  5    l_cur sys_refcursor;
  6  
  7    procedure OpenAndPopulateCursor(p_cur in out sys_refcursor) is
  8    begin
  9      open p_cur for
 10        select *
 11         from dual;
 12    end;
 13  
 14  begin
 15    OpenAndPopulateCursor(l_cur);
 16  
 17    if l_cur%isopen
 18    then
 19      fetch l_cur bulk collect into clientID_nt;
 20    end if;
 21  
 22    dbms_output.put_line(concat( to_char(clientID_nt.count) 
 23                               , ' record(s) has/have been fetched.'));
 24  end;
 25  /

 1 record(s) has/have been fetched.

 PL/SQL procedure successfully completed
```

Comment: @Rachcha Do you know the type(how many columns and of what data type each of them) that ref cursor is returning? You probably can get that information by exploring source code of `myProc` procedure. If you know the type and it differs from `some_table%rowtype` then you might declare a record type which has as many fields as many of them ref cursor contains and those fields are of compatible data types.