# Access out parameters of a procedure from another procedure in oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a procedure which returns some columns using select statement:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE test_ref(
           OUT_RESULT         OUT SYS_REFCURSOR )
        AS
        BEGIN
          OPEN OUT_RESULT FOR 
            SELECT NAME,AGE,CODE FROM SOMETABLE;
        END;
```

I need to access this procedure and fetch the values from the select statement

```
create or replace 
PROCEDURE TESTPROC AS 
OUT_RESULT sys_refcursor;
BEGIN
 test_ref(OUT_RESULT);
END TESTPROC;
```

How do I loop and get name,age,code out of OUT_RESULT?

Something like:

```
LOOP
         FETCH out_result INTO SOMETHING;
         EXIT WHEN out_result%NOTFOUND;
      END LOOP;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're almost there.  What you want to do is:

1. Obtain (FETCH) the result set of the query (a SYS_REFCURSOR is a pointer to a query).
2. Get the columns you need from the result set by placing results into a record (row-by-row) or a collection.

I would recommend bulk collecting into a collection since bulk operations are always more efficient.  Example of a collection ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19562603/fetch-and-bulk-collect-from-a-ref-cursor-returned-by-a-procedure)):

```
SQL> declare
  2    TYPE t_clientID_nt IS TABLE OF dual%rowtype;  --TYPE <type_name> IS TABLE OF <record_name>
  3    clientID_nt t_clientID_nt;  --Create a variable for the table type
  4  
  5    l_cur sys_refcursor;
  6  
  7    procedure OpenAndPopulateCursor(p_cur in out sys_refcursor) is
  8    begin
  9      open p_cur for
 10        select *
 11         from dual;
 12    end;
 13  
 14  begin
 15    OpenAndPopulateCursor(l_cur);  --Returns your SYS_REFCURSOR via IN OUT parameter
 16  
 17    if l_cur%isopen
 18    then
 19      fetch l_cur bulk collect into clientID_nt;  --Bulk collecting into the table variable (collection) we created above
 20    end if;
 21  
 22    dbms_output.put_line(concat( to_char(clientID_nt.count) 
 23                               , ' record(s) has/have been fetched.'));
 24  end;
 25  /
```

If you need to use row-by-row fetching for some reason ([source](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/using-ref-cursors-to-return-recordsets)):

```
DECLARE
  l_cursor  SYS_REFCURSOR;
  l_ename   emp.ename%TYPE;
  l_empno   emp.empno%TYPE;
  l_deptno  emp.deptno%TYPE;
BEGIN
  get_emp_rs (p_deptno    => 30,
              p_recordset => l_cursor);

  LOOP 
    FETCH l_cursor
    INTO  l_ename, l_empno, l_deptno;
    EXIT WHEN l_cursor%NOTFOUND;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(l_ename || ' | ' || l_empno || ' | ' || l_deptno);
  END LOOP;
  CLOSE l_cursor;
END;
/
```

Comment: Thanks a million bro. You are a saviour